# Как перенести логику в контроллер и использовать в шаблоне blade?

Tags: laravel

Здравствуйте помогите плиз я новичок в Laravel у меня есть код Ajax и есть логика которую он должен использовать я хотел бы перенести её в контроллер и использовать в шаблоне blade но как пока не понял`

```js
//это файл "feedback_lib.php" чью логику я хотел бы перенести в контроллер и использовать в шаблоне AJAX
<?php

  //Помогите плиз уже 3 дня не могу связать это в одно целое
  
 $message = $_POST["message"];
  
  $error = false;
 
 if (trim($message) == 0)  $error = true;
 
 echo getAnswer($result);
 
 function getAnswer($error) {
  
   if($error) {
      
   $answer = "<p style='color: red;'>Введите сообщение</p>";
      
      } else {
      
      // и сохранить в БД
      
      //$mes = new Message();
      //$mes->from = $_REQUEST["from"];
      //$mes->to = $_REQUEST["to"];
      //$mes->message = $_REQUEST["message"];
      //$mes->save();
      
   $answer = "<p style='color: green;'>Сообщение отправлено</p>";
  }
    
  return $answer;
 }
 
?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/JavaScript">

   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contact").submit(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
      url: "feedback_lib.php",// тут он должен использовать логику этого файла 
      //  как перенести эту логику в контроллер и тут использовать + сохранить данные в Бд
      //  которые передаются Post методом в этот файл с проверкой сообщения?
      beforeSend: function() {
       $("#load").fadeIn(400);
      },
      type: "post",
      data: $("#contact").serialize(),
      success: function(answer) {
       $("#answer").html(answer);
      }
     }).done(function() {
      $("#load").fadeOut(400);
     });
    });
   });

  </script>

 </head>
 <body>
  <form id="contact" action="" name="contact" method="post">
   @csrf
   <?php print_r($_REQUEST)?><br>

   <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="10" cols="40" placeholder="сообщение"></textarea>
   <br />
   <button name="send">отправить</button>
  </form>
  {{--<img id="load" src="load.gif" style="display: none;" />--}}
  <div id="answer"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: Пожалуйста, изучите документацию laravel.ru . Фреймворк лишь помогает вам работать с языком и предоставляет отличное окружение и набор готовых решений, зачем вы, не научившись использовать яп, трогаете фреймворк, притом что в документации, в видео-уроках все подробно описано несколько раз.

Answer (score 1):

В контроллере создаешь функцию

```
public function contact(Request $request) {
    $message = $request->input('message');
    if(!$message) {
        $answer = "<p style='color: red;'>Введите сообщение</p>";
    } else {
        // и сохранить в БД
        //$mes = new Message();
        //$mes->from = $request->input('from');
        //$mes->to = $request->input('to');
        //$mes->message = $request->input('message');
        //$mes->save();
        $answer = "<p style='color: green;'>Сообщение отправлено</p>";
    }
    return $answer;
}
```

Добавляешь роут

`Route::post('/contact', 'тут контроллер@contact')->name('contact');`

И в шаблоне

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/JavaScript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#contact").submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{route('contact')}}",// тут он должен использовать логику этого файла
                    //  как перенести эту логику в контроллер и тут использовать + сохранить данные в Бд
                    //  которые передаются Post методом в этот файл с проверкой сообщения?
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $("#load").fadeIn(400);
                    },
                    type: "post",
                    data: $("#contact").serialize(),
                    success: function(answer) {
                        $("#answer").html(answer);
                    }
                }).done(function() {
                    $("#load").fadeOut(400);
                });
            });
        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="contact" action="" name="contact" method="post">
    @csrf
    <?php print_r($_REQUEST)?><br>

    <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="10" cols="40" placeholder="сообщение"></textarea>
    <br />
    <button name="send">отправить</button>
</form>
{{--<img id="load" src="load.gif" style="display: none;" />--}}
<div id="answer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Как вариант в контроллере можно возвращать **response()->json($data);** . Плюс лучшим решением было бы возвращать только текст, без html кода. Но это дело вкусовщины, боюсь автор не поймет что делать, раз задает такие вопросы.

Comment: Спасибо большое nicolaa Ваш ответ помог